# Mac: Compressed Image Error

Tags: mac

Attempting to install Ubuntu on my mac, using Etcher with the Ubuntu provided ISO file by following [this Canonical tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview) but i get the error:

> Something went wrong. If it is a compressed image, please check that
>   the archive is not corrupted.

I've tried twice with fresh downloads. Anyone know how to get past this step?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu that you are attempting to install?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the file is not corrupt check for its hash value

Install this package:

```
brew install md5sha1sum
```

After that run the command:

```
md5sum /directory/of/iso/file
```

After installing, `google` for the hash value of whichever version of `ubuntu` you're trying to run and compare the `hash` value

Comment: I ran this and I got the error that the file couldnt be read, interesting.

Comment: you should `replace` that to where your file is located `/directory/of/iso/file` wherever your `ubuntu.iso` file is located

Comment: haha, i did. still getting failed to open or read.

Comment: You can't install unless you have a valid ISO to install with.

Comment: try downloading again if you cannot confirm if the file is not `corrupt`

Answer (score 0):

If the file integrity is not the issue, as midrizi suggested, you can try using a different tool like Unetbootin. You can also use the built-in dd tool, if you're comfortable using the command line. You can find a guide here. https://www.cybrary.it/blog/0p3n/macos-terminal-create-bootable-usb-iso-using-dd/